# Google returns new identity string while logging in with Loginza

Tags: oauth, openid, google-oauth

There is a web-site that uses Loginza for logon and registration. For each user it stores identity - for Google it is:

https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmyGLT0M1aDf_CCysqh2EPhwq5o_avd4EU

for example.

For a year everything was ok, but recently Google started to return new different identities for registered users (that didn't change their Google account) - so they are treated as newcomers.

Can somebody explain me why is it happening and what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: How recently? Do you know the day or time?

Comment: A week ago, but it seems that the reason is that Google returns different identities for different domains, and for him www.domain.com is not equal domain.com. But I don't know why is it so (other providers don't change identity for different domains - fb or twitter, for example) and how can I tell Google that it is the same site.

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify an 'openid.realm' parameter. See these two

http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#realms

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#Parameters

for the request parameters. It's listed as optional, but if you leave it out (not recommended) we have to try to figure out the realm from return_to parameter.

This is from the google docs:

"This value must be consistent with the domain defined in openid.return_to. If this parameter is not defined, Google will use the URL referenced in openid.return_to.

The value of realm is used on the Google Federated Login page to identify the requesting site to the user. It is also used to determine the value of the persistent user ID returned by Google."

If realm changes, the directed identifier for the user will change.

Comment: But I don't do any request to Google - it is done by Loginza and I can't change anything there.

Comment: Then you should follow up with Loginza, you might want to reference this question when you do.